# How to extract downloadable links inside table containing list of links, and scrape multiple pages

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I would like to extract all .doc links when clicking into a specific title (i.e. announcement in this case) inside table.

I am able to extract title, date, and all links in the **first level** for **only one page** as per code below:

```
from lxml import etree
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import sys
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlparse, urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

frame =[]

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options)

for page_number in range(1,78):
    url = 'http://example.com/index{}.html'.format(page_number)

driver.get(url)
html = etree.HTML(driver.page_source)

extract_announcements_list = html.xpath('//table[@id="14681"]/tbody/tr/td/table[@width="90%"][position()>=2 and position() <= (last())]')
for i in list:
    date = i.xpath('./tbody/tr/td[3]/text()')
    title = i.xpath('./tbody/tr/td[2]/font/a/@title')
    link = i.xpath('./tbody/tr/td[2]/font/a/@href')
    real_link = 'http://example.com'+ link[0]
    print(title,date,real_link)

frame.append({
    'title': title,
    'link': real_link,
    'date': date,
    **'content': doc_link,** #this is the doc_link I want to extract in the second level
        })

dfs = pd.DataFrame(frame)
dfs.to_csv('myscraper.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

I am trying hours to search for a solution for this. I would really appreciated if someone can help me extract the second link to get content for the .doc link ('content': doc_link), as well as way to scrape all pages in the website.

Thank you very much in advance!

**UPDATED:** Many thanks to @Ares Zephyr for sharing your code. Here is what I have made to my code as per suggestion. But it did not yield any results for being able to get the inside links.

```
from lxml import etree
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import sys
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

frame =[]

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options)

for page_number in range(1,2):
    url = 'http://example.com/index{}.html'.format(page_number)
    print('Downloading page %s...' % url)

    driver.get(url)
    html = etree.HTML(driver.page_source)
    html_page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")

    extract_announcements_list = html.xpath('//table[@id="14681"]/tbody/tr/td/table[@width="90%"][position()>=2 and position() <= (last())]')
    for i in list:
       date = i.xpath('./tbody/tr/td[3]/text()')
       title = i.xpath('./tbody/tr/td[2]/font/a/@title')
       link = i.xpath('./tbody/tr/td[2]/font/a/@href')
       real_link = 'http://example.com'+ link[0]

          soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(real_link).content, 'html.parser')
          for doc_link in soup.findAll('a'):
             thelink = doc_link.get('href')

             frame.append({
               'title': title,
               'link': real_link,
               'date': date,
               'doclink': thelink,
               })

dfs = pd.DataFrame(frame)
dfs.to_csv('myscraper.csv',index=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Why isn't everything in the for loop? You are only getting the last page. for page_number in range(1,78): <- everything up to the append has to be in here. Also your frame.append needs to be in the other for loop.

Comment: @arundeepchohan previously I can use this code for page_number in range(1,78): and it works pretty well in other pages, I am just not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here, and I can just only get the last page in Python, and when exporting into csv file, just only the last announcement+date+link of that last page appears. I am thinking maybe I put inside the loop or something. Many thanks if you could help me with this.

Comment: You should put it in the for loop. Your looping through and reinitializing the values everytime and then appending it only once.

Comment: Thank you so much @arundeepchohan. It's working now. Just wondering, could you be so kind to advise how to amend my code to scrap all the web pages and get all the .doc links when clicking inside the links in the table? Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @arundeepchohan UPDATED: I've just amended my code by indenting all in order. I'm able to scrap all pages now. Now the problem just left with extracting all the .doc links. Many thanks if you could advise me on that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to indent this piece in your code for the append function to work on all your scraped data. I believe that is what @arundeep-chohan is also trying to highlight.

```
frame.append({
    'title': announcement_title,
    'link': real_link,
    'date': announcement_date,
    **'content': doc_link,** #this is the doc_link I want to extract in the second level
        })
```

The logic to find doc files is as follows. Please modify and use it. This is part of my code that I use to download pdf files.

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
  theLink = link.get('href')
  name= link.string

  # Logic to find .pdf files
 
  if theLink[-4:]  == ".pdf" or theLink[-4:] == ".pdf":
    if theLink[-4:] ==".pdf":
      fileExtension = ".pdf"
```

Comment: My bad, I didn't realise it initially. It is working as intended now. Just wondering, could you be so kind to advise how to amend my code to scrap all the web pages and get all the .doc links when clicking inside the links in the table? Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since the site is in foreign language is quite hard to navigate the pages and debug. However, I did notice xlsx files present and they are all stored as links on the site. You can look for tags with 'href' with extension .doc or .docx and that you get you all the urls/possibly download the files as well.

Comment: UPDATED: I've just amended my code by indenting all in order. I'm able to scrap all pages now. Now the problem just left with extracting all the .doc links. Many thanks if you could advise me on that.

Comment: @Tracy I've updated the code above to include a piece that will help you achieve finding the doc files. just use the extension appropriately. .doc or .docx

Comment: Thank you, your edit really means to me. I'm just wondering if you could take a look at my updated code as I got errors while running this. I think it's due to the Requests sent to the page. I've tried to scrap the first 2 pages.

Comment: Hi @ Ares Zephyr I still don't get the desired results of getting the doc link inside. I'm hoping you can help me look into this. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Tracy The code that you have right only only digs into the first page. My suggestion is use the code to fetch all the data you need and then use the file as a reference URLs for the secondary pages to fetch all the pages that have the doc file using the second bit of the code I shared to find .doc or docx files.